# (Duda) ¿El garbage collector limpia las variables creada en un metodo estatico? Y si no es asi, ¿como puedo liberar la memoria en esos casos?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un proyecto de una libreria .net framework. En el tengo unas clases que heredan de Window que utilizo como InputsDialogs.

luego tengo una clase estatica cuyos metodos instancian las ventanas respectivamente y devuelve lo que se introduce en la ventana. Ejemplo corto.

```
public static class Interactions
{

    public static string InputPasswordDialog(string message, string title = "InputPassword")
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        Windows.InputPasswordDialog inputPasswordDialog = new InputPasswordDialog(message,title);

        inputPasswordDialog.ShowDialog();

        output = inputPasswordDialog.Password;

        return output;

    }
```

dicho esto, ahora aclaro mi pregunta. ¿despues de invocar el metodo estatico, las variables como "inputPasswordDialog" son liberadas por el garbage collector, o no lo hace por ser estatico? y en caso de que no se liberen, como puedo hacer para liberarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variables locales de método (o simplemente "variables locales" como se les llama normalmente) se asignan en la pila de cada hilo. Las variables en sí mismas no están sujetas a recolección de basura. Se reclaman automáticamente cuando la llamada al método termina (normal o anormalmente).

Los objetos son otro asunto. Los objetos (incluidas las matrices) normalmente se asignan en el heap y están sujetos a la recolección de basura.

Entonces, ¿qué pasa con un objeto (o matriz) que se asigna mediante un método y se asigna a una variable local?

En primer lugar, la variable local tiene una referencia al objeto. El objeto se almacena en el heap.

Cuando se ejecuta el recolector de basura (y generalmente no sabe cuándo será), verificará las variables locales existentes en busca de llamadas a métodos que aún estén en progreso. Si las variables contienen referencias a objetos, esos objetos se agregan a la lista de objetos que se deben mantener ... y se verifican las referencias a otros objetos, y así sucesivamente.

Entonces, en resumen, las variables locales se destruyen automáticamente cuando finaliza la llamada al método, pero los objetos a los que se refieren esas variables continuarán existiendo hasta que el GC (eventualmente) descubra que son inalcanzables.